# `viewer.navigation.fitBounds` without margin

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I want to create high resolution screenshots of a specific image section. My approach is to create multiple screenshots from each quarter of my section (top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right). For that I am using `viewer.navigation.fitBounds`. However, there seems to be a little margin which I wanna get rid of because I cannot stitch the quarter screenshots together easily.

Is `viewer.navigation.fitBounds` supposed to fit the bounds perfectly and therefore, is it a usage error on my side?

##### Example

The black markers represent my bounding box for upper right screenshot which I use when calling `Autodesk.Viewing.ScreenShot.getScreenShotWithBounds`. However, there is some space left between the black markers and the top and bottom border.
[image: Shows viewer after fitBounds]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `Navigation.fitBounds` uses `Navigation.computeFit` which uses the following margin settings adding 5% by default to each side:

```js
  // Change these constants to alter the margin ratios (think, percentages/100).
  // The margins are how much to add above and below. For example, setting the
  // margin to 25% (0.25) would give a margin of 25% above, 50% in the middle for
  // content, and 25% below. This value should never be >= 0.50, as that would
  // leave no area for the content to display.
  // The offsets are how much to shift the view. For example, shifting 50% (0.50)
  // vertically would move the displayed area such that only the bottom half of
  // the drawing area would be seen.
  this.FIT_TO_VIEW_VERTICAL_MARGIN = 0.05;
  this.FIT_TO_VIEW_VERTICAL_OFFSET = 0.00;
  this.FIT_TO_VIEW_HORIZONTAL_MARGIN = 0.05;
  this.FIT_TO_VIEW_HORIZONTAL_OFFSET = 0.00;
```

You can set these variables anywhere before calling `viewer.navigation.fitBounds`:

```js
const viewer = NOP_VIEWER; // your viewer instance
viewer.navigation.FIT_TO_VIEW_VERTICAL_MARGIN = 0.0;
viewer.navigation.FIT_TO_VIEW_HORIZONTAL_MARGIN = 0.0;
```